# how to contribute the same source code to two separate open-source projects?

Tags: open-source, licensing

Let's say there are two similar open source projects A and B, both licensed under the Apache Software License 2.0.

I would like to contribute an improvement to both projects (because I don't know which one is administered better, and I would like to see my improvement show up in both).

Is there a way I can contribute this improvement to both projects in a simple way? (One obvious approach is to start an open source project C licensed under Apache 2.0, but that's a headache for various reasons; I don't want to maintain a project myself)

Answer (score 2):

What prevents you from contributing the code to both projects? It’s *your* code, you have the copyright and can do with it whatever you want (within reasons). In particular, you can give the copyright (or parts) to whomever you please – that includes multiple recipients.

There are exceptions (e.g. in print publishing where the publisher requires an *exclusive* copyright, or when you write the code on company time in which case you don’t own the copyright to start with) but this isn’t usually the case with Open Source projects.